# How can I chain Django's "in" and "iexact" queryset field lookups?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a list of names, e.g.:

```
name_list = ['Alpha', 'bEtA', 'omegA']
```

Currently I have the following queryset:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name__in=name_list)
```

I would like to be able to filter the names in a case-insensitive fashion. My first thought was to use the `iexact` field lookup but it doesn't seem to work with `in`. How can I use the `iexact` with the `in` field lookup for my queryset? Or is there an alternate way to perform this query?

Comment: `in` cannot do case-insensitive, you would have to iterate over each item do `iexact` and use `Q` objects to combine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's my solution, which uses [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) instead:

```
name_list = ['Alpha', 'bEtA', 'omegA']
q_list = map(lambda n: Q(name__iexact=n), name_list)
q_list = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, q_list)
MyModel.objects.filter(q_list)
```

Comment: +1 good job, this also good. I will use it for future reference

Comment: I think Derek's answer is very nice, but I wonder if from django 1.7 it's possible to write a custom lookup to achieve the same thing?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-lookups/

Comment: Just a note: in python 3 you will need to import `reduce` from `functools` since it is no longer a keyword.

Comment: Can anyone explain what this is actually doing? I understand the map part, but not sure what passing the reduce function into the filter is doing.

Comment: I created a helper function to wrap this pattern for re-use: https://pastebin.com/raw/cBH8UNz5. You can call it like `query_in_iexact(MyModel.objects, name_list, 'name')`

Comment: @nhinkle it's an alternative way of spelling `MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name__iexact='Alpha') | Q(name__iexact='bEtA') | ...)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
name_list = ['Alpha', 'bEtA', 'omegA']
results = MyModel.objects.none()
for name in name_list:
    results |= MyModel.objects.filter(name__iexact=name)
```

Ok I test it and it works :)

Comment: `contains` is different from `exact` match.

Comment: @Rohan it's "icontains" not "contains". If you read the Django documentation thoroughly then you know the difference between contains and icontains.

Comment: yes you are right @cathy but `exact` gives the exact match but `contains` gives the results if object match with any letters in given query in this case we may get unwanted results :)

Comment: @kartheek yeah I know the difference of that but you don't get it. He said "iexact" not "exact". They have different functions. Read this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: No this is wrong, `exact`, `iexact`, `contains`, and `icontains` don't work with lists. The only field lookup that works with lists is `in`. If you run the code you have suggested, you will also find out that it doesn't work.

Comment: What I get mad is he down voted me for not correct reason. Why he said "contains" and "exact". The question above is pointing about "iexact" not "exact". They are different. I just give another sample of case-insenstive function.

Comment: @DerekKwok I will accept that my code doesn't work and you down voted me. It's ok for me. I can search and try again to make it work and so that your problem will fix. But I will not accept the other reasons that are not correct!

Comment: yeah @cathy we can use this if we want objects contains the query i used this kind of query one of my project and am not downvote for you but why u removed your comment for my ans :(

Comment: @cathy I did not downvote you. You can check my reputation history/activity.

Comment: @DerekKwok then thanks, will then I go searching for your problem and sorry for my wrong codes. I did not test that.

Comment: @cathy this ans was in my last comment in my ans :( any way good job this should work

Comment: @cathy i think we can use `results += mymodel.objects.....` right tell me if am wrong

Comment: @kartheek  Thanks also, I test it and it works. Don't be sad you can also get votes from other questions

Comment: @kartheek If I use that I will get error like this: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'

Answer (score 3):

How about annotating the target record with the transformed name as lower case? Should reduce the number of conditions required considerably, boosting performance...

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

lcase_name_list = [x.lower() for x in name_list]
MyModel.objects.annotate(lcase_name=Lower('name').filter(lcase_name__in=lcase_name_list)
```

Comment: Some of the other solutions are a little simpler, but this solution scales much better for very large list of names to match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a list comprehension. It is similar to catherine's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907590/3003133), but with one database hit like Derek Kwok's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908214/3003133) (but procedural instead of functional).

```
q_list = Q()
for q in [Q(name__iexact=n) for n in name_list]:
    q_list |= q
MyModel.objects.filter(q_list)
```

For those that like to avoid zip, map, reduce, and such in Python.