# how to use queryset filter attribute depending on array in django?

Tags: python, arrays, django, python-2.7, django-queryset

if i have :

```
data= request.data['participants'] 
Conversation.objects.filter(participants = data).values()
```

where data is an array of participants, i want to get conversations which have those participants in.

i want compare an array to a foreign key(one to many) to get conversation which contains those participants.

```
      {
        "conversation_id": 38,
        "created_at": "2017-08-14T09:15:19.776000Z",
        "name": "first conversation",
        "participants": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "zezor93",
            },
            {
                "id": 64,
                "username": "tasus22",
            }
        ]

    }
```

**Conversation model:**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(_("file title"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Conversation Serializer:**

```
class ConversationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    participants = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        fields = '__all__'
```

the reason i want to filter depending on array of participant, that when i create a conversation of a set of participants i need to know if there is a conversation with those exact participant so i will not create it i just will return it, if they are not the exact participants i will create a new conversation.

Comment: Check `in` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: `in` will return any conversation contain one of those participants .. i want to get conversation that have only this set of participants array in `data= request.data['participants'] `

Comment: your Conversation contains many participants or one participant?post your model may help. you want to get conversation that have only this set of participants array in data= request.data['participants'],what do you mean by only?

Comment: @Ykh i need to get the conversation that has the exact same participants..

Answer (score 0):

```
Conversation.objects.filter(participants__id__in = [x['id'] for x in data]).values()
```

Comment: i need to get the conversation that has the exact same participants.. i mean your solution will return conversations which has `participants` of `id=1` or `id=64`

Answer (score 0):

```
Conversation.objects.filter(participants__username__in = [participant['username'] for participant in data]).values()
```

I'm  not exactly sure about what you are intending to do. [Hope this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907525/how-can-i-chain-djangos-in-and-iexact-queryset-field-lookups)

Comment: i need to get the conversation that has the exact same participants..
i mean your solution will return conversations which has `participants` of `id=1` or `id=64`

Comment: @zezor93 I have changed the answer so that now it can be filtered using `user_name'

Comment: yes i can see that .. however this will return any conversation has zezor93 or any conversation has tasus22 .. i want to return  conversation which has `zezor93` and `tasus22` only with each other.

Comment: please post your models

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907525/how-can-i-chain-djangos-in-and-iexact-queryset-field-lookups